# Using parameters with setInterval reverses them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot for the life of me understand what is happening here. I am trying to use function.bind in a setInterval to pass some variables. What is happening is that only one parameter is being passed, and it is replacing the first one. I think maybe I am either misusing bind, or there .bind is conflicting with jquery's .bind? I am clueless at this point.

Please open the console and check out what happens when you click the div.

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/v2zc6mtm/5/

```
    var testA, testB;

function myFunc(testA, testB) {
    console.log("testA is : " + testA + " testB is : " + testB);
}

myInterval = setInterval(myFunc.bind(testA, testB), 5000);

$('#myDiv').click(function () {
    testA = "foo";
    testB = "bar";
    myFunc(testA, testB);
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(myFunc.bind(testA, testB), 5000);
});
```

Comment: Pass `this` as your first variable into the setInterval bind call, ie `myInterval = setInterval(myFunc.bind(this, testA, testB), 5000);`

Comment: Avoid using `.bind()` because its not backward compatible. `setInterval()` takes either an anonymous function or a function name like a variable or the result of `.bind()` which I'm not recomending. Wrap that like: `setInterval(function(){myFunc(testA, testB)}, 5000);`.

Comment: @PHPglue - That is incorrect. The reason bind works is because it is a function handle, which setInterval also accepts. Moreover, your example will not work. Bind itself is *not* a function call. It returns a function. As a result that code will never cause anything to happen. Further `.bind(testA,testB)` is the same misconception the OP had about `bind` and you can see an explanation from either Nicolas or ScottW on the proper way to use it. `testA` in your code will become the `this` context, `testB` will be passed to `testA` and `testB` will receive undefined.

Comment: To be honest, Nicolas Alberts code works, and it works on the latest FF, and that's all my client is using. :)

Comment: @tdoakiiii - The use of bind in this case serves no purpose and is bad practice because it wastes resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `this` parameter of `bind`, so you should write something like:

```
myInterval = setInterval(myFunc.bind(this, testA, testB), 5000);
```

`this` can be any JS Object. This is the same for `call` and `apply` of a function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Here your edited fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/v2zc6mtm/6/

Comment: GOD. If that mozilla manual didn't intimidate me so maybe I would spend more than 3 seconds RTFM... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bind does't work like you are thinking I believe. Bind is for injecting `this` into an execution context. It is not for passing arguments if `this` is not a concern. In order to pass arguments, you are going to want to use an anonymous function like this

```js
var testA, testB;
console.log = function(arg){$("#console").html(arg);}//used only for demo snippet

    function myFunc(testA, testB) {
     console.log("testA is : " + testA + " testB is : " + testB);
    }

    myInterval = setInterval(function(){ myFunc(testA, testB); }, 5000);

    $('#myDiv').click(function () {
     testA = "foo";
     testB = "bar";
     myFunc(testA, testB);
     clearInterval(myInterval);
     myInterval = setInterval(function(){ myFunc(testA, testB); }, 5000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:8px">
 <h3>Console</h3>
    <div id="console"></div>
</div>
<div id="myDiv">Click</div>
```

Comment: Would love to hear the explanation of inaccuracy with this answer.

Comment: bind() curries arguments as well as freezing _this_, often eliminating the need for extra anon wrappers.

Comment: @dandavis "freezing" `this` is an incorrect way to phrase that. `bind` replaces `this` in the current Execution Context for the function bound. *However*, that is the most minimally invasive part of it. It also does a large amount of setup manually constructing a Function object. Using an "anon wrapper", or anonymous function, has a far smaller footprint than bind. Using bind is overkill here, as all the extra work setting up the **new** Function object is wasted when the context is never used. *Bind does not eliminate the need for an anonymous function*.

Comment: if bind doesn't eliminate the need for an anon, how come the accepted answer doesn't use an anon? i also don't see how a function object created by bind() would be any heavier than a function object created by an anon literal...

Comment: @dandavis - The accepted answer merely shows the OP's choice, which was to correct a simple syntax error in the way the method was called. Accepting an answer does not mean that process is correct or best practice, but that is a meta issue. Perhaps you should do some self education so that you know the difference between the anonymous function and what bind creates.

Comment: i know the difference, which is why i'm confused by your comments. bind-created functions should be lighter than anons; primarily, they have no prototype or closure, and they need not resolve _this_ or formal parameters at call time. with so much less happening on a bind-result than an anon, i would need to see some supporting info to buy into your notion that anons would leave a "far smaller footprint than bind"... and besides, the function only fires once every 5 seconds so unless there is some more compelling aspect, perf is relatively un-important in this case.